# cannot chown file as root

Tags: linux, permissions, mount, chown

After mounting a NTFS or fat32 partition (not as readonly), I try to change it to my user permissions with

```
sudo chown user: file
```

However I am then told that the "Operation is not Permitted".
I have read that could because of immutable set, When I try something like:

```
sudo chattr -i file
```

I am told "Inappropriate ioctl for device while reading flags file/

Does anyone have any other ideas to chown my drive?

Comment: change filesystem type to another which supports posix permissions.

Comment: See [How do I correctly mount a NTFS partition in /etc/fstab?](http://askubuntu.com/a/113746/18979) or [How do I use 'chmod' on an NTFS (or FAT32) partition?](http://askubuntu.com/a/11843/18979) on Ask Ubuntu

Comment: The exporting or sharing host may have permissions set up so that you can't do what you want.